# I'm trying to insert a text but the input field on my local terminal won't let me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

As you can see the code from my Visual Studio Code, it won't let me type within the text input if I render the code

[image]

Comment: Could you explain your problem in more detail? What are you trying to do, what do you expect to happen, what's actually happening? Also, please include the code for the rest of your component.

Comment: I posted an image of the code

Comment: Copy-pasted code is preferred to images of code as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onChange event on **line 36** invokes (updateInput) function.
Which doesn't exist or declared inside the component, if you sent it as a prop use :

`this.props.updateInput(_params_)`

**Otherwise declare the function inside the component in order to make the event work properly.**

[image]

Comment: It works now thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's because `<input />` has constant value, so you need to change `value` to `defaultValue`.

```
<input 
  type="text"
  placeholder="Insert text"
  defaultValue={this.state.newItem}
  onChange={() => {}}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked the code and it works now!

Comment: Great, if this solves the problem, please accept the answer.